# How to implement a sandbox testing with google checkout in drupal ubercart

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, google-checkout

I have a drupal6 site with ubercart module installed. 
I have also enabled the Google checkout module that came inbuilt with ubercart.

But i am unsure about how to setup a sandbox testing account with Google checkout.
Is there any reference or manual for the steps to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create sandbox accounts, see more info [there](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134469).

Comment: After creating the sandbox accounts, do i need to configure those settings under test environment settings of the google checkout configuration, and enable the test mode?

Comment: Yes, you should enable test mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed document explaining how to use the Checkout Sandbox environment:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox.html